# How Do I Specify Read and Write Capacity Units for AWS Amplify Tables So I Can Move Away From On-Demand Tables?

Tags: aws-amplify

**Problem:**

The AWS Amplify CLI does not offer options to move away from "on-demand" usage, to provisioned for DynamoDB tables. Thus, I would like to specify this information in the CloudFormation stack.

What is the best practise for this? I would like to sustain the changes written as infrastructure as code for future deployments.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the steps:**

1. Go to your `amplify/backend/api/[projectName]/parameters.json` folder
2. Find the `DynamoDBBillingMode` and change it to `"PAY_PER_REQUEST"`
3. Add `"DynamoDBModelTableReadIOPS": 1,` below `DynamoDBBillingMode` to set the reads for all tables
4. Add `"DynamoDBModelTableWriteIOPS": 1,` below `DynamoDBModelTableReadIOPS` to set the writes for all tables

These three key/value pairs should be in the route table.

Final JSON:

```
{
  "AppSyncApiName": "name",
  "DynamoDBBillingMode": "PROVISIONED",
  "DynamoDBModelTableReadIOPS": 1,
  "DynamoDBModelTableWriteIOPS": 1,
  ...
}
```

**How To Customise Reads and Writes Per Table:**

1. Create an `override.ts` file in the same folder as your `parameters.json` file
2. Specify your billing mode like this example: `resources.models["Contact"].modelDDBTable.billingMode = "PROVISIONED";`
3. Specify your read and write capacity units like this example: `resources.models["Contact"].modelDDBTable.provisionedThroughput = { "readCapacityUnits": 1, "writeCapacityUnits": 1 };`

Final JSON:

```
{
   resources.models["Contact"].modelDDBTable.billingMode = "PROVISIONED";
   resources.models["Contact"].modelDDBTable.provisionedThroughput = { "readCapacityUnits": 1, "writeCapacityUnits": 1 };
}
```